# PHP прочитать файл *.doc

Tags: php, ms-word

У меня есть код, который открывает и читает файлы msword *.doc, именно *.doc, не *docx.
Если в файле только текст - то все считывается хорошо, но вот если в файле есть содержание, то к каждому пункту добавляются какие то спецсимволы, например:

> HYPERLINK \l "_Toc282581517" 1.1 Экономическая сущность кредитования  PAGEREF _Toc282581517 \h 6

Сам код:

```
function read_doc($filename) {
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    
    if (($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false) {
        $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);
        $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );
        $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );
        $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );
        $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );
        $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);

        $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
        $extracted_plaintext = mb_convert_encoding( $extracted_plaintext, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE' );
        return nl2br($extracted_plaintext);

    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

}

Как можно доработать код, чтобы не было этих спецсимволов?

Comment: Скачать библиотеку для php для чтения doc файлов.

Comment: @ArchDemon  не, это не вариант, я регуляркой допилил получившийся текст и все заработало как надо)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение)
Доработал код регулярными выражениями:

```
        $extracted_plaintext = preg_replace('#().*?()#', '$1$2', $extracted_plaintext);
        $extracted_plaintext = preg_replace('#().*?()#', '$1$2', $extracted_plaintext);

        $extracted_plaintext = str_replace('', "", $extracted_plaintext);
        $extracted_plaintext = str_replace('', "", $extracted_plaintext);
        $extracted_plaintext = str_replace('', "", $extracted_plaintext);
```